# Create a nested array recursively in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, recursion

Following is my array

```
[
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: {number:0}},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: {number:0}},
    {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: {number:1}},
    {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: {number:3}},
    {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: {number:4}},
    {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: {number:4}},
    {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: {number:3}},
    {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: {number:2}}
]
```

and I want to have objects nested like this as output :

```
[
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
            {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [
                {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
                {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4}
            ]},
            {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3}
        ]}
    ]},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
    ]}
]
```

Please help me with a recursive function to do this in node.js.

Following is the recursive function is what I have tried:

```
    function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var out = []
    for(var i in arr) {
        if(arr[i].parent.number == parent.number) {
            var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

            if(children.length) {
                arr[i].children = children
            }
            out.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Please help me to solve this. I am a newbie in this.

Comment: What have you tried?  We aren't really a coding service.  You really ought to make some attempts yourself and then ask us questions about where you got stuck.

Comment: This is what I have tried but could not upload it.function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var out = []
    for(var i in arr) {
        if(arr[i].parent.number == parent.number) {
            var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

            if(children.length) {
                arr[i].children = children
            }
            out.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return out
}

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please put the code you tried into your question, format it properly and then explain what result you got or where you got stuck and more specifically what you want help with in that code.  Multiline code is not legible in comments.  You can use the "edit" button to edit your question to add the code you tried and the additional explanation.

Comment: I am able to upload my code now thanq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renaming some variables helped me solve this.

- `getNestedChildren` returns an array of children, so rename `out` to `children`.
- the children returned by the recursive call are the grandchildren of the parent being processed in the call. So call the result of the recursive call `grandchildren`.

The problem that caused the code to not work:

- line 4 of the posted code uses the `id` property of the parent parameter. So either ensure that every call to `getNestedChidren` provides an object with such a property (as below), or change the second argument to `parentNumber` and just supply the numeric value of the `number` property. Your choice.

Lastly, avoid using `for ... in` loops to iterate an array - please do a web search for more information and discussion.

```js
var array = [
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: {number:0}},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: {number:0}},
    {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: {number:1}},
    {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: {number:3}},
    {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: {number:4}},
    {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: {number:4}},
    {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: {number:3}},
    {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: {number:2}}
]
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var children = [];
    for(var i =0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if(arr[i].parent.number == parent.number) {
            var grandChildren = getNestedChildren(arr, {number: arr[i].id})

            if(grandChildren.length) {
                arr[i].children = grandChildren;
            }
            children.push( arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return children;
}
var nest = getNestedChildren(array,{number: 0});
console.log( nest);
```

Comment: @traktor53 - How would solve this if your array was more flat?

Comment: I couldn't comment all that code here, so I wrote a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone wants to know the solution with a flattened initial array, as per user992731's request:

```js
var array = [
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
    {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1},
    {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3},
    {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
    {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4}
];

function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var children = [];
    for(var i =0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if(arr[i].parent == parent) {
            var grandChildren = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id);
            if(grandChildren.length) {
                arr[i].children = grandChildren;
            }
            children.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return children;
}
var nest = getNestedChildren(array,0);
console.log(nest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This old question was resurrected by an new answer, which has since been deleted.

But I thought it's worth adding a simpler solution:

```js
const nest = (xs, id = 0) => xs
  .filter (x => x .parent .number == id )
  .map ((x) => ({...x, children: nest (xs, x. id)}))

const input = [{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: {number:0}}, {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: {number:0}}, {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: {number:1}}, {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: {number:3}}, {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: {number:4}}, {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: {number:4}}, {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: {number:3}}, {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: {number:2}}]

console .log (nest (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Our function creates a tree by accepting a flat list and the root id (defaulted to `0`), filtering to find all elements with matching parent id, then for each one, adding its children by recurring using the current element's id as the root.  Note that we don't need an explicit base case, because `filter` will simply return an empty array when we're done, and hence we won't recur in the `map` call.

Note that this includes an empty `children` array in the leaf nodes.  If that's a problem, a slightly more complex variant will skip them:

```js
const nest = (xs, id = 0) => xs
  .filter (x => x .parent .number == id)
  .map ((x) => (
    (children = nest (xs, x .id)) => ({...x, ...(children .length ? {children} : {})})
  )())

const input = [{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: {number:0}}, {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: {number:0}}, {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: {number:1}}, {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: {number:3}}, {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: {number:4}}, {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: {number:4}}, {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: {number:3}}, {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: {number:2}}]

console .log (nest (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```